# RODBC Cursor Queries

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

Im new to R - but im looking to execute an SQL server cursor query across multiple databases on an SQL Server and store the results in a dataframe - I have connected to the server and I have a separate file with the SQL -

SQL (cursor_query.sql) -

```
CREATE TABLE #tempRPT
(date DATE, 
 number  INT,
 type nvarchar(255)
);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @DBNAME NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR STATIC
FOR SELECT [name]
    FROM sysdatabases; 
OPEN dbcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @DBNAME;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'USE  ['+@DBNAME+']; 
        select
cast(startdatetime as date),
count(*),
''bookings''
from bookings
group by cast(startdatetime as date);'
        INSERT INTO #tempRPT
        EXEC (@sql);
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @DBNAME;
    END;
CLOSE dbcursor;
DEALLOCATE dbcursor;
SELECT *
FROM #tempRPT;
DROP TABLE #tempRPT;
```

im trying to read this into R with the following -

```
Results <-
  sqlQuery(
    odbcConnect(dsn = "Database", uid = "***", pwd = "***"),
    query = readLines("cursor_query.sql", warn=FALSE)
  )
```

But I dont get any results - any ideas or a suggestion of how to do this?

Comment: First try with a simple select query. If it works, try with a permanent table in your query and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RODBC queries supports only one SQL statement per `sqlQuery` call. Your attempted procedural query consists of multiple statements. Additionally, you are running dynamic SQL with loops, two things R can do for you without temp tables.

Consider retrieving all database names then iterate across each for your aggregate query. Notice the use of period qualifiers to query from other databases on same server. Finally, concatenate all to a final, single data frame object.

```
conn <- odbcConnect(dsn = "Database", uid = "***", pwd = "***")

db_names <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT [name] FROM sysdatabases")

df_list <- lapply(db_names$name, function(db) 
         sqlQuery(conn, paste0("select
                                  cast(startdatetime as date) as start_date,
                                  count(*) as [count],
                                  'bookings' as [indicator]
                                from [", db, "]..bookings
                                group by cast(startdatetime as date)")
         )
)

final_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)

odbcClose(conn)
```

Comment: thanks - this is working when I run it across a handfull of databases, but when I try to run across all of them it completes but doesnt seem to return any results - any suggestions?

Comment: See slight edit passing in a vector, `dbnames$name`, into `lapply` and not whole data frame. Also, do all database tables use the `dbo` schema? Specifically, relay any errors and describe if `df_list` and/or `final_df` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

[SET NOCOUNT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) at the beginning of the batch.  Rowcount messages sent after DML statements have to be processed by the client before it reads the resultset.  SET NOCOUNT ON suppresses these messages so clients generally can't tell the difference between a single-statement SELECT batch and a multi-statement batch with a single SELECT as one of the statements.